# char[] vs char in argument of method. Is this a Mistake in MS documentation?

Tags: c#, methods, documentation

According to Microsoft documentation:

Method Split in system.string namespace takes an array of char as an argument.

```
public string[] Split(
    params char[] separator
)
```

I know i can use it like this:

```
string[] myarray1=null;    
string somestring="Hi, My name is Tamara";
myarray1=somestring.Split(','); // i used char, not char[] and everything works fine...
```

My question is why this method works fine ? I used char, not an array of chars.
I cannot fathom this. Maybe the question is very stupid, but trying to improve my understanding of documentation ;/

Comment: `params char[]` means you can call the method like this: `.Split('a', 'b', 'c')`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) Tamara and see if you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the keyword `params`. It means, that you can call the method without creating a char array: `.Split('a', 'b', 'c')`. But, if you already have a char array, you can also call the method like this:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
string somestring="Hi, My name is Tamara";
var s = somestring.Split(chars);
```

The first way is just syntactic sugar.

From [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params):

> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration or an array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no arguments. If you send no arguments, the length of the params list is zero.